# Where was the Blake's 7 episode "Rumours of Death" filmed?

Tags: film-location, blakes-7

I've not been able to identify the stately home that features as "Residence 1" in the *Blake's 7* episode "Rumours of Death". I think it should be quite recognisable.

Does anyone know where it is?

[image: Location of Residence 1]

Comment: Blakes-7 fandom site states "Oxfordshire" as a filming location, if that helps at all

Comment: https://www.countrylife.co.uk/property/oxfordshire-country-house-rent-86489 ?

Comment: https://humanrace.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/cornbury-park.jpg ? Which I think is the same as in my previous comment.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  Do you have a reason for suggesting the specific mansion Cornbury Park?  My answer comments on your suggestion.

Comment: I googled "oxfordshire mansions" and switched to the images tab, and found one that kinda looked like the one in the vague picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding to the above, as I think the Cornbury suggestion nailed it *(and is confirmed in the linked pages of the answers and below)*:

[image]

Complete with giant tree to the right.

https://watchingblakes7.wordpress.com/2018/06/17/c08-rumours-of-death-and-a-bit-about-death/

[image]

> Lets take the location of ‘Residence One’.  It would appear that Blake’s 7 isn’t the only series that Cornbury Park in Oxfordshire has hosted.

This page also has a couple of comparison shots:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I remembered a scene from a Blake's 7 episode.

I just watched the begining of "Rumors of Death" online and the scene I remembered was in it.

I thought that the mansion I remembered from that scene had a pedimented portico with about 4 columns.  But there is no portico in exterior shots of the mansion, so it appears my memory is faulty and the mansion is even less impressive than I rememberd.  I always thought that claiming the mansion cost more than building two new cities was an incredbily extreme exaggeration - whatever happened to the proverbial British understatement -  and now it appears that the exaggeration is even more extreme.

From what I have seen of the exterior of the mansion so far, it could be Cornbury Park, as BCdotWEB suggests in his comments.  Or maybe one of perhaps a hundred other English mansons with a similar style.

I suppose that if someone watches the episode to the end the end credits might have locations listed.

Answer (score 3):

At the suggestion of @BCdotWeb, I did a Google search for "Cornbury Park Blake's 7" and was directed to [information about the house](https://www.thedicamillo.com/house/cornbury-park-cornbury-house-blandford-house/).

Among a number of other television drama appearances (*Inspector Morse*, *Father Brown*) this specific *Blake's 7* episode is listed.